# xpages - Cannot search the word "Field"

Tags: xpages

I found a strange problem in Xpages search. If I search for the word "Field" I am getting below error messages.

The field name used in the query cannot be found in the database

I checked with several Xpages database and all getting the same issue. If I add any character\symbol to the word field, it will work. For example " field."  or " "field" ".

Do anyone face this issue? Is this a known bug?

Appreciate your feedback.

Thanks

Sooraj

Comment: Can you add the code you are using for searching?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is a bug.  FIELD is a reserved word in NSF searching.

Comment: So, how if someone wants to search the word\sentence contains the "Field"? Any alternative solution for this?

Comment: Try including it in quotes. FIELD is different to "FIELD". Including search content in quotes is best practice anyway. If the value is multiple words, you'll notice different results and not the ones you're expecting unless you use quotes.

Comment: Thanks. Also found a couple of other words(AND, OR) that cannot be searchable in xpages. Can we hardcoded this(" ") in search option or need to manually type for each search?